# Get smaller decimal number from larger integer number

Tags: java, numbers, number-formatting

Sorry for a possible duplicate post, I saw many similar topics here but none was exactly I needed. My question is, suppose I have one large integer number,

```
int i = 1234567890;
```

I want to convert it into the decimal number with maximum 2 decimals, but the decimal number should fit into the range from 0 to 10. i.e. it could be like below,

```
0.1 or 0.9 or 2.3 or 4.2 or... upto below 10;
```

How should I convert larger integer number into smaller decimal number. Does anyone can help me with the formula, which will work for any larger number, really struggling on it.

Comment: And you want to do this in Java *and* C?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to *scale/map* integers into some real range?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that there are more integer numbers than two-digit decimal floating point numbers? This "conversion" is probably not going to be entirely lossless...

Comment: @Biffen I am not concerned about technology it could be any technology, just looking for a solution/formula to fix this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I want to scale it to some real range, by using some kind of mathematical formula.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin right now I am just concerned about scaling down to some real number range by using some mathematical formula.

Comment: @TusharDigambarDeshpande "some mathematical formula" is pretty vague... Do you want to scale it linearly such that 0 is mapped to 0 and 10000000000 is mapped to 10.0 or what? Divide by billion. And don't use integers, because they go up to just 2.x billion.